# Netty - number of concurrent client connections

Tags: netty

I am running a test against my application running on Netty server (4.0.28.Final)

## On OSX

Without setting the below code it does not support concurrent client (1024)
connections

```
option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 2048)
```

After this setting I am able to make 1000s of concurrent client connections.

Q1 Having `ulimit` set to 2048 and `somaxcon` set to 2048 didn't help, Why?

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited

    $ sysctl -a | grep files
    kern.maxfiles = 10000
    kern.maxfilesperproc = 10000
    kern.maxfiles: 10000
    kern.maxfilesperproc: 10000
    kern.num_files: 2098

    $ sysctl -a | grep somax
    kern.ipc.somaxconn: 2048

Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377450/maximum-number-of-open-filehandles-per-process-on-osx-and-how-to-increase
```

Q2 `netstat` on the port gives me the right count of connections(1024) but lsof gives a much lesser value(175).

## On Centos

The following setting works for huge client connections

```
option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)

os level
Ulimit = 65336
# sysctl -a | grep somax
net.core.somaxconn = 128
```

Q3 I am able to connect multiple clients. Why/How? Note: All values except ulimit are high.

Q4 What does setting backlog do? Why is it required on OSX and no effect on CentOS?

Q4 Netty on my OSX logs this message

```
23:17:09.060 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn: 128 (non-existent)
```

I created /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn. The log started showing the new value but it had no effect on number of concurrent thread.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html has details on the backlog parameter. Increasing this value on OSX to get it working is like fooling the system? The queue becomes long and not the actual physical connection. I was able to get proper count of lsof when I ran nginx with set value of ulimit and targeted it with high concurrent clients.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for all the confusion.

echo limit maxfiles 10000 10000|sudo tee -a /etc/launchd.conf as indicated in the other thread worked for me.

lsof now shows expected count and it works with backlog of 128 :)