# How to increase limits on sockets on osx for load testing?

Tags: macos, sockets, freebsd, libev

I'm creating a load tester that uses libev to create lots of open tcp connections to an app i'm working on. Currently it bombs out at 256 connections, due to the nofiles limit:

```
ulimit -n
256
```

I can increase this to 1024 by doing the below:

```
ulimit -n 1024
```

But i cannot increase it further. Ideally i want to set it to 1048576. It gives the following error:

```
ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument
```

How can i increase the ulimit further on osx?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

(answer updated to use -S as several commenters suggested)

```
$ sysctl kern.maxfiles
kern.maxfiles: 12288
$ sysctl kern.maxfilesperproc
kern.maxfilesperproc: 10240
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfiles=1048600
kern.maxfiles: 12288 -> 1048600
$ sudo sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=1048576
kern.maxfilesperproc: 10240 -> 1048576
$ ulimit -S -n
256
$ ulimit -S -n 1048576
$ ulimit -S -n
1048576
```

Comment: Odd - i tried that on my home mac (snow leopard) and it didn't work, but on my work mac (also snow leopard) it worked fine. Hmm...

Comment: Can you elaborate on these settings? I assume `maxfilesperproc` means "per process," and it makes sense it has to be less than `maxfiles`, but is there any reason you chose that specific number?

Comment: The original question mentions "Ideally i want to set it to 1048576.".  The `maxfiles` was choosen as "something slightly larger than 1048576", there was no reason for it to be this particular value.

Comment: I just found this article that explains more about these settings: http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/maximum-files-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: Also, I had to use `ulimit -S -n 2048` to see it change.

Comment: Doesn't work for os x 10.8.2 :( However, with `-S` option it works. Please update your answer.

Comment: seems not working on 10.7.5, it's again reset to 1024, tried even from `sudo -s`

Comment: Is there a way to make it persistant, because it resets when I open a new window.

Comment: Bob Ebert: the sysctl part should be permanent until reboot.

The ulimit part can be made permanent by putting it into your shell profile file, such as /etc/bashrc, /etc/zshrc, ~/.bashrc, ~/.zshrc.
Alternatively, you can do the equivalent of ulimit from within your program by using the setrlimit(2) syscall.

Answer (score 6):

One more thing: Limit on ports is 65535. So you may not get as many as you want to.

Answer (score 2):

Try running as root (e.g. do a "sudo -s" before running the ulimit command and your program).

Note that I'm not sure that 1-million-plus TCP sockets at once is realistically achievable (although I'm interesting in hearing about what happens when you try it ;^))

Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166783/how-to-increase-the-limit-of-maximum-open-files-in-c-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: Well, 1M connections might not be realistic, but we'll see how far i can go. Just don't want to be artificially limited by ulimits.