# Firing many requests at a node app for test causing socket hang up / ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js, express, brute-force, supertest

I'm trying to write a test for my application, where by I've used [express-brute](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-brute) to prevent brute force attacks.

I have the following test:

```
it('should return 429 status after 1000 attempts', function (done) {
    this.timeout(5000);

    var counter = 0;

    var makeRequest = function (count, done) {
        counter++;
        request(app)
        .post('/login')
        .send({ username: 'a+' + count + '@b.com', password: 'wrong' + count })
        .end(function (err, res) {

            if (err) {
                console.log('failed request #', counter); 
                return done(err);
            }

            if (counter < 1001) {
                makeRequest(counter, done);
            }
            else {
                res.header.location.should.equal('/account/login');
                res.statusCode.should.equal(429);
                done();
            }
        });
    }

    makeRequest(counter, done);
});
```

Which throws either error:

> Error: socket hang up
>   sometimes it is 
>   Error: read ECONNRESET

It's always around connection # 225

The same test (with only 20 or so requests) works fine (if i change my express-brute config)

What's causing it to error out?

Am I not closing / disposing the connections correctly?

Answer (score 2):

What operating system do you use?

It may be necessary to increase the amount of allowed open sockets.

For example see here: [How to increase limits on sockets on osx for load testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578594/how-to-increase-limits-on-sockets-on-osx-for-load-testing)

Comment: I'm glad you asked this; On windows, it seems to work fine. On OSX, I have this problem.... I thought I was going mad!

Comment: Yeah, the answer listed on that question does the trick... just annoying that I have to do that on every dev machine :-s

Comment: @Alex glad you found the problem! Is it then necessary to have so much connections for development?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate a resource exhaustion problem by using this code, which I believe replicates the essentials of your problem:

```
var request = require("supertest");
var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.post('/login',
    function (req, res, next) {
        res.send('Success!');
    }
);

var server = app.listen();

var counter = 0;

function makeRequest(count, done) {
    counter++;
    request(app)
        .post('/login')
        .send({ username: 'a+' + count + '@b.com', password: 'wrong' + count })
        .end(function (err, res) {

            if (err) {
                console.log('failed request #', counter);
                done(err);
            }

            if (counter < 1001) {
                console.log(counter);
                makeRequest(counter, done);
            }
            else {
                console.log(res);
                done();
            }
        });
}

function done(err) {
    process.exit(1);
}

makeRequest(counter, done);
```

And running it like this:

```
$ (ulimit -n 100; node test.js )
```

I have to use `ulimit` because whatever causes your problem does not happen on my OS. The `ulimit` command limits the number of open files to 100. When I run it like above, request number 89 fails. (There are a bunch of other files opened to run the script, which explains why it fails at request 89 rather than 100.)

I can get the code to run to completion if I change the code so that I create a server from my app:

```
var app = express();
// ...
var server = app.listen();
```

and I use `server` in `request` instead of `app`:

```
request(server)
    .post('/login')
// ...
```

So using what `app.listen()` returns should fix the issue.