# Erlang raise number of opened sockets, MacOS and CentOs

Tags: macos, sockets, erlang, connection

I'm trying to open connections (**sockets**) to my **Erlang** server; everything works fine with around 100 paralell connections, but when I want more than 100 i get {error, closed}.

It may be something that has to do with **OS file descriptor limit**? If yes, can you guys please give me a solution? I use MacOS and CentOS.

Should I give some params to the Erlang Vm in vm.args file?

Comment: See `ulimit -n`. Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578594/how-to-increase-limits-on-sockets-on-osx-for-load-testing) for MacOS for example

Answer (score 0):

Open sockets limit in erlang relies on two things:

1. OS max open files limit, you can check how two tune it [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/tuning/open-files-limit/#Mac-OS-X)
2. Erlang VM `+Q` flag for max open ports, check out it [here](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html)

Comment: You are right, those steps are required, but I also need to pass an argument to the listen call. That is the {backlog, SomeNumber}. The default value is 5 for backlog. With these 3 steps I did what I wanted, thanks for help.

Comment: I still didn't work for more than around 100 connections, on ssl:connect I receive econnreset

Comment: It is little bit tricky to apply all these changes. I am not a MacOS advanced user, so I can give advice how to check things under linux:

Comment: with help of `ps aux | grep beam` find erlang vm process id, then `cat /proc/PID/limits | grep "Max open files"`. Make sure that it is the same as you set in OS limits.