# Erlang TCP sockets get closed

Tags: erlang, gen-tcp

To learn Erlang I am trying to implement a tiny web server based on `gen_tcp`. Unfortunately, my code seems to trigger some wired behaviour. To demonstrate the problem I have attached a minimised version of my implementation which is sufficient to reproduce the problem. It is just delivering a static 200 OK, no matter what the HTTP request was.

The problem arises when I try to run `ab` (Apache HTTP server benchmarking) against my web server (using loopback interface). Without any concurrent requests (`-c`) everything is running just fine. However, if I use `-c 8` or `-c 16`, the call to `gen_tcp:accept/1` seems to fail on some sockets as I see a number of `request: closed` lines in the shell.

What makes the whole story even weirder is, that I see different behaviours on different operating systems:

- OS X+Erlang/OTP 18: `ab` reports "Connection reset by peer" almost immediately after starting.
- Debian+Erlang R15B01: All but two of the HTTP requests seem to run through. But then, `ab` hangs for a few seconds and reports "The timeout specified has expired, Total of 4998 requests completed", when i run `ab` with `-n 5000`. Similarly, 14998 is reported when I run 15000 tests.

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32410172/erlang-raise-number-of-opened-sockets-macos-and-centos) does not seem to be the problem. I am honestly quite lost and therefore appreciate any help! :) Thanks!

```erl
server(Port) ->
    Opt = [list, {active, false}, {reuseaddr, true}],
    case gen_tcp:listen(Port, Opt) of
        {ok, Listen} ->
            handler(Listen),
            gen_tcp:close(Listen),
            ok;
        {error, Error} ->
            io:format("init: ~w~n", [Error])
    end.

handler(Listen) ->
    case gen_tcp:accept(Listen) of
        {ok, Client} ->
            request(Client),
            handler(Listen);
        {error, Error} ->
            io:format("request: ~w~n", [Error])
    end.

request(Client) ->
    Recv = gen_tcp:recv(Client, 0),
    case Recv of
        {ok, _} ->
            Response = reply(),
            gen_tcp:send(Client, Response);
        {error, Error} ->
            io:format("request: ~w~n", [Error])
    end,
    gen_tcp:close(Client).


reply() ->
    "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n" ++
    "Content-Length: 7\r\n\r\n"
    "static\n".
```

Comment: If you can, try this on a different platform, such as Linux. I've found in the past that `ab` on OS X is just horribly broken. I ran your code on Linux with `ab -c 100 -n 5000 http://localhost:...` and it ran just fine.

Comment: @SteveVinoski: Thank you for your comment. I tried on a all new Ubuntu installation. You are right, it works much more stable there. With the fix presented bellow, it also runs smooth on OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you increase the number of concurrent requests sent with `ab -c N` it will immediately open multiple TCP sockets to the server.

By default a socket opened with gen_tcp:listen/2 will support only five outstanding connection requests.  Increase the number of connection requests outstanding with the {backlog, N} option to gen_tcp:listen/2.

I tested your code on OS X with ab and saw this resolve the prolem with "Connection reset by peer".

Comment: Thank you! Works form me as well on OS X at list for `N` <= 128. Have you succeeded in running with  `-c 256` ?  In my case there seems to problem even if i set `ulimit -n 2048`, start erlang with `+Q 2048` and backlog 2048 ports.