# CLOSED error when establishing lots of connections with gen_tcp in parallel (Bug?)

Tags: sockets, erlang, gen-tcp

When trying to establish a largeish number of TCP connections in parallel I observe some weird behavior I consider a potential bug in `gen_tcp`.

The scenario is a server listening on a port with multiple concurrent acceptors. From a client I establish a connection by calling `gen_tcp:connect/3`, afterwards I send a "Ping" message to the server and wait in passive mode for a "Pong" response. When performing the 'get_tcp:connect/3' calls sequentially all works fine, including for large number of connections (I tested up to ~ 28000).

The problem occurs when trying to establish a lot of connections in parallel (depending on the machine between ~75 and several hundred). While most of the connections still get established, some connections fail with a `closed` error in `gen_tcp:recv/3`. The weird thing is, that these connections did not fail before, the calls to `gen_tcp:connect/3` and `gen_tcp:send/2` were both successful
 (i.e. returned `ok`). On the server side I don't see a matching connection for these "weird" connections, i.e. no returning `gen_tcp:accept/1`. It is my understanding, that a successful 'get_tcp:connect/3' should result in a matching accepted connection at the server side.

I already filed a [bug report](http://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-160), there you can find a more detailed description and a minimal code example to demonstrate the problem. I was able to reproduce the problem on Linux and Mac OS X and with different Erlang versions.

My questions here are:

1. Is anyone able to reproduce the problem and can confirm, that this is erroneous behavior?
2. Any ideas for a workaround? How to deal with this problem, other starting all  the connections sequentially (which takes forever)?

Comment: Without looking at the example my first thought is that the tcp `backlog` size might be too small. Have you tried raising it? (http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_tcp.html#listen-2)
See http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html for a description of what it does.

Comment: I agree with @johlo. I looked into your code and you're not using the `{backlog, B}` option. Possible duplicate of [Erlang TCP sockets get closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511676/erlang-tcp-sockets-get-closed)

Comment: @johlo Thanks, great tip and great link. Increasing the backlog solved the problem and the article explains why the call to `gen_tcp:connect/3` returns  without error (because it got the SYN/ACK from the server and sent the final ACK), but the server does not end up in state established (because it ignored the final ACK).

Comment: I started to answer the question, based on the suggestions from @johlo. Feel free to help improve the answer. I am still a bit unclear on why the problem is only identified when the client tries a receive, and not in the send. Is this specific to how send and receive work? Or is this due to timings (server was still retrying `SYN-ACKs` when the send was attempted)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP 3-way handshake
            Client         Server

```
  connect()│──┐          │listen()
           │  └──┐       │
           │      SYN    │
           │        └──┐ │
           │           └▶│   STATE
           │          ┌──│SYN-RECEIVED
           │       ┌──┘  │
           │   SYN-ACK   │
           │ ┌──┘        │
   STATE   │◀┘           │
ESTABLISHED│──┐          │
           │  └──┐       │
           │     └ACK    │
           │        └──┐ │   STATE
           │           └▶│ESTABLISHED
           ▽             ▽
```

The problem lies with the finer details of the 3-way handshake for establishing a TCP connection and the queue for incoming connections at the listen socket. See this [excellent article](http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html) for details, much of the following explanation was informed by this article.

In Linux there are actually two queues for incoming connections. When the server receives a connection request (`SYN` packet) and transitions to the state `SYN-RECEIVED`, this connection is placed in the `SYN` queue. If a corresponding `ACK` is received, the connections is placed in the accept queue for the application to consume. The `{backlog, N}` (default: 5) option to `gen_tcp:listen/2`  determines the length of the access queue.

When the server receives an `ACK` while the accept queue is full the `ACK` is basically ignored and no `RST` is sent to the client. There is a timeout associated with the `SYN-RECEIVED` state: if no `ACK` is received (or ignored, as is the case here), the server will resend the `SYN-ACK`. The client then resends the `ACK`. If the application consumes an entry from accept queue before the maximum number of `SYN-ACK` retries has been reached, the server will eventually process one of the duplicate `ACKs` and transition to state `ESTABLISHED`. If the maximum number of retries has been reached the server will send a `RST` to the the client to reset the connection.

Coming back to the behavior observed when starting lots of connections in parallel. The explanation is, that the accept queue at the server fills up faster than our application consumes the accepted connections. The `gen_tcp:connect/3` calls on the client side return successfully as soon as the receive the first `SYN-ACK`. The connections do not get reset immediately because the server retries the `SYN-ACK`. The server does not report these connections as successful, because they are still in state `SYN-RECEIVED`.

On BSD derived system (including Mac OS X) the queue for incoming connections works a bit different, see the above mentioned [article](http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html).